# Rotation slerp to unity quaternion

Tags: rotations, quaternions

The context: A graphic application in which the user rotates an object around the origin and then can press a button to reset the rotation to its reset state. The reset should be appear smooth and not just jump.

I'm using a quaternion to represent the current rotation of the object at any time and when the user presses the button I want to `slerp()` between the current rotation and the reset one. This works fine if the reset rotation is a real rotation with Theta and an Axis but it breaks down if the reset state is has theta=0.

The slerp starts with a standard rotation quaternion

```
q1 = sin(theta/2) + (xi + yj + zk)cos(theta/2)
```

and supposed to end at the rotation quaternion with theta=0:

```
q0 = sin(0/2) + (xi + yj + zk)cos(0/2)
```

which turns out to be the the unit quaternion:

```
q0 = 1+0i+0j+0k
```

The problem I'm facing is that to do the rotation, slerp calcs the angle alpha between `q0` and `q1` by just taking their vector parts and doing `arccos()`, but the unity quaternion's vector is (0,0,0) so it can't do that.

Is there a standard way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please don't use codeblocks for something which is not actual code. [MahJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) should be used to typeset equations and mathematical text.

Comment: For what reason do you need to compute the angle $\alpha$ between the vector parts of $q_0$ and $q_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it... First of all your definition of a quaternion is wrong.  The correct expression is:

$$q_1 = \cos(\theta/2) + (xi + yj + zk)\sin(\theta/2)$$

and

$$q_0 = \cos(0/2) + (xi + yj + zk)\sin(0/2) = 1 $$

where $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1$. 
Since $q_1$ represents the forward rotation, then the inverse is just the conjugate (i.e. negate the vector part).

$$q_1^{-1} = \cos(\theta/2) - (xi + yj + zk)\sin(\theta/2)$$

We can then divide the reverse rotation into N steps by dividing the angle by N yielding

$$q_{slerp} = \cos(\frac{\theta}{N}/2) - (xi + yj + zk)\sin(\frac{\theta}{N}/2)$$

This rotation is then applied to all of the points in your rotated shape object N times to bring it to the reset position.